# Are there English toponyms that are pluralia tantum?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, proper-nouns, toponyms, pluralia-tantum

There are toponyms that are pluralia tantum in a few languages.  What come off top of my mind are Mediterranean cities in classical languages, such as *Athenae* and *Pompeii*.  A modern example I can come up with is *Karlovy Vary* (literally, Charles' Baths) in the Czech Republic.

These toponyms are plural not only morphologically but also syntactically.  For instance, [this paragraph](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karlovy_Vary#Spr%C3%A1vn%C3%AD_%C3%BAzem%C3%AD) from the Czech Wikipedia article on Karlovy Vary starts off by saying that it is a regional city: *Karlovy Vary jsou krajským městem*.  Here the copula *jsou* is in its plural form.

I am wondering if similar toponyms exist in English as well.  Cities like *Las Vegas* or *Los Angeles* are plural morphologically, but I don't think anybody says "Los Angeles *are* beautiful in winter."  The second paragraph of the Wikipedia article on The Bahamas reads "The Bahamas *were* inhabited by the Lucayans," but I'm not sure if this is strictly about the country, or they are talking about the islands.

Comment: I never heard anyone refer to a single [***Norfolk Broad***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Broads#:~:text=The%20Broads%20(known%20for%20marketing,counties%20of%20Norfolk%20and%20Suffolk.&text=The%20area%20is%20303%20square,120%20mi)%20of%20navigable%20waterways.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for a list.

Comment: There are island groups and mountain ranges, but I guess you're more interested in a town or other place you would expect to have a singular name?

Comment: The Smokies are treated this way by locals. [The Great Smoky Mountains are a mountain range rising along the Tennessee–North Carolina border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Smoky_Mountains)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even though I could have, I actually did not ask for a list in my original post.  (I was actually skeptical if there was any at all.)  Fell free to edit my post so it may be clear that this is not asking for a list.

Comment: @StuartF  You are right.  Like Pompeii and Athenae, not so much like The Bahamas.

Comment: I've never seen a Trossach. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trossachs

Comment: @OldBrixtonian hank you.  But this does not seem to be plural in terms of verb agreement, though (based upon the Wikipedia article at least).

Comment: There's the paved pedestrian area in the centre of Tunbridge Wells: [*Queen Anne provided the tiled paving after which **The Pantiles are** named.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22paving+after+which+the+Pantiles+are%22) But personally I'd probably go with Wikipedia as regards the plurality: [***The Pantiles is** a Georgian colonnade in the town of Royal Tunbridge Wells.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pantiles)

Comment: @Pteromys Wiki says, "The Trossachs **form** part of ...", "The Trossachs **were** one of the first..." Am I misunderstanding something? (It happens a lot!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have lived a sheltered life? Broads in the Norfolk Broads have a name. For example: Oulton Broad in https://www.thesuffolkcoast.co.uk/suffolk-coast-towns-and-villages/oulton-broad. There are others.

Comment: @Anton: Based on the average number of fingers, I'd say it's the Norfolkians who've been living the sheltered lives (they need to get out more and meet people with different dna! :)

Comment: Devizes in Wiltshire used to be called _The Devizes_, but I haven't found any evidence that it  was spoken of in the plural.

Comment: The Shambles in York. ("officially just 'Shambles'" according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shambles). From an obsolete name for an open-air slaughterhouse.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian 'The Trossachs' is obviously plural in form, but I'd say is more often given singular agreement nowadays ('The Trossachs is a lovely region to visit").

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is this part of the English country called "[The Downs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Downs,_Bristol)"; you  write  "The Downs **are** …" rather than "The Downs is" ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Downs+are%2CThe+Downs+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20Downs%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThe%20Downs%20is%3B%2Cc0#)).